# Javascript page to send credentials

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

**JavaScript File**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function send()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }




xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

xmlhttp.open("POST","192.168.0.10/unp.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(encodeURI("Username="+document.form1.uname.value+"&password="+document.form1.pass.value));





}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<form name="form1" method="post">
USERNAME:<input type = "text" name="uname"><br>
PASSWORD:<input type = "password" name="pass">


<br>



<input type="submit" onclick="send()">
</form>
<div id="myDiv"><p>How are You </p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP file running on the server**. I want to store the credentials in a file on the server

```
<?php
$myfile="testfile.txt";
$fh=fopen($myfile,'a');
$stringdata=$_POST["Username"];
$stringdata1=$_POST["password"];
fwrite($fh,$stringdata);
fwrite($fh,$stringdata1);
fclose($fh);
?>
<html>
Details Submitted
</html>
```

The client page loads without error. The file textfile doest get created though.
The response also is not returned. Is the Js file correct?

Comment: how are you accessing the page in your browser?

Comment: i have the html code wrtten in notepad,am opening it with IE,with ActiveX content enabled.

Comment: i have the server on VirtualBox,Linux server with apache on ,

Comment: so Actually your URL looks like this: `file://foo` right?

Comment: Disclosure: I'm thinking about Same Origin Policy here

Answer (score 1):

Were you expecting "Details submitted" to appear *on the screen*?  From your code (which looks as the current document), it appears you think so but no, that is not the case.  The text would be in `xmlhttp.responseText` and parsed out neatly in `xmlhttp.responseXML`.

**EDIT**

Vinod's comment pointed out some other errors in his code, in particular, his encoding was wrong (which probably was not the problem he was seeing) and the headers were missing (which probably was).  He should have written:

```
var params = "Username="+encodeURIComponent(document.form1.uname.value)+
         "&password="+encodeURIComponent(document.form1.pass.value);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xmlhttp.send(params);
```

Comment: Ya, i was ,it worked when i was making a GET request.I also wanted the credentials stored inthe file on the server.

Comment: I tried your changes too, still giving same response as before.

Comment: Install Firebug and look at what is really being sent.  Write an HTML page with a form that posts to 192.168.0.10/unp.php.  Compare.